# Не работает программа c std::thread

Tags: c++, многопоточность, concurrency, c++11

Не могу понять почему программа с std::thread, то зависает при запуске, а то работает нормально, компилятор MinGW-w64. Видимо ловлю в какойто момент взаимную блокировку, но вот понять в какой не могу. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
mutex m0,m1,m2,m3,m4;
condition_variable c1,c2;
vector <int> vInt;
bool b1 = false;
bool b2 = false;
int b0=2;
bool ext = false;

void add_vect(int i) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(m0);
    vInt.push_back(i);
};

void gen() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk1(m3);
    for (int i=1; i<6; ++i) {
        if (i>1) { // в перовой итерации цикла пропускаем ожидание окончания работы потоков ex1, ex2
            c2.wait(lk1,[]{return b0 == 2;}); //ожидание окончания работы потоков ex1, ex2
        };
        add_vect(1); //тут должна быть функция выполняемая в этом потоке
        m4.lock();
            b0 = 0;
            b1=true;
            b2=true;
            if ( i == 5 ) ext = true; // проверяем последнюю итерацию цикла
            c1.notify_all(); //разблокируем потоки ex1, ex2
        m4.unlock();
    };
};

void ex1() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk1(m1);
    while (!ext) {
        c1.wait(lk1, []{ return b1; }); //ожидание окончания работы потока gen
        for (int i = 1; i<10; ++i) {
            add_vect(2); //тут должна быть функция выполняемая в этом потоке
        };
        m4.lock();
            b1=false;
            b0++;
            if (b0 == 2) //проверяем что этот поток последний завершает работу
                c2.notify_one(); //разблокируем поток gen
        m4.unlock();
    };
};

void ex2() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk1(m2);
    while (!ext) {
        c1.wait(lk1, []{ return b2; });
        for (int i = 1; i<10; ++i) {
            add_vect(3); //тут должна быть функция выполняемая в этом потоке
        };
        m4.lock();
            b2=false;
            b0++;
            if (b0 == 2) //проверяем что этот поток последний завершает работу
                c2.notify_one(); //разблокируем поток gen
        m4.unlock();
    };
};

int main()
{
    thread tgen(gen);
    thread t1(ex1);
    thread t2(ex2);
    tgen.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    for (vector <int>::iterator it=vInt.begin(); it != vInt.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

По времени потоки должны работать так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: gen должен дождаться старта ex1 и ex2 (точнее, если вызвать c1.notify_all, а ex1 и ex2 еще не вызвали c1.wait, то notify пропадет, а в дальнейшем ex1 и ex2 повиснут на своем с1.wait) Тут этот момент как-то уже обсуждался мной и @VladD для pthreads (к сожалению не помню вопроса, попробуйте поискать).

Comment: Начнём с того, что доступ к разделяемым переменным типа `ext` у вас не охраняется никаким мьютексом. Это неправильно.

Comment: Затем, какова цель мьютексов `m1`, `m2`, `m3`? Ответ: никакой. Они каждый используется локально в своём потоки, ни никого ни от кого не защищают. Если их выкинуть, ничего в логике выполнения не поменяется.

Comment: Затем, ожидание по cond var нужно проводить при залоченном соответствующем мьютексе. А у вас что? У почему-то отправка `notify` производится под мьютексом `m4`, а вот ожидание — вовсе без мьютекса. Разгребайте завалы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам скелет, должно в принципе работать. Обошёлся одним общим мьютексом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

mutex global;

condition_variable allow_ex_cond;
int allow_iteration = -1;

condition_variable finished_ex_cond;
int finished_ex = 0;

bool shutdown = false;

const int num_workers = 2;

void gen()
{
    cout << "coordinator working, iteration -1" << endl;

    const int maxiterations = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxiterations; i++)
    {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);

            // start new iteration
            finished_ex = 0;
            allow_iteration = i;
            shutdown = (i == maxiterations - 1);

            allow_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // wait for threads to finish task
            finished_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return finished_ex == num_workers; });
        }

        // do work
        cout << "coordinator working, iteration " << i << endl;
    }
}

void excommon(int num)
{
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // do work
        cout << "worker " << num << ", iteration " << iteration << endl;

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(global);

            // signal finished
            finished_ex++;
            if (finished_ex == num_workers)
                finished_ex_cond.notify_all();

            // check exit
            if (shutdown)
                break;

            iteration++;

            // wait for signal to continue
            allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [iteration] { return allow_iteration == iteration; });
        }
    }
    cout << "worker " << num << " shutting down" << endl;
}

void ex1()
{
    excommon(1);
}

void ex2()
{
    excommon(2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    thread tgen;

    {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(global);
        tgen = thread(gen);
        allow_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return allow_iteration == 0; });
    }

    thread t1(ex1);
    thread t2(ex2);

    tgen.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: все хорошо работает пока вместо 
        cout << "worker 1, iteration " << iteration++ << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
не использовать например добавление в массив.
тогда поведение такое же как и в моем случае, программа зависает

Comment: @xttz: А вы случайно не выполняете работу под мьютексом?

Comment: @xttz: Вроде подправил по мелочам. Но если что-то не работает, выкладывайте ваш код.

Comment: Спасибо, последний вариант работает просто прекрасно. Буду разбираться, как и что, но основное понятно, нужно защищать мьютексом участки, которые изменяют и проверяют флаги, а не сами потоки (как было у меня)

Comment: единственное в Gen() **заменить** if (!shutdown) { // wait for threads to finish finished_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return finished_ex == 2; }); } } cout << "coordinator working, iteration " << i << endl; **на** // wait for threads to finish finished_ex_cond.wait(l, [] { return finished_ex == 2; }); } if (!shutdown) cout << "coordinator working, iteration " << i << endl; иначе перед завершением gen() выполняется два раза подряд, прежде чем запустятся два других потока.

Comment: @xttz: кстати, обнаружил ещё один race condition: запускать `gen` нужно под локом. Обновил ответ, проверяйте.

Comment: @xttz: и `allow_iteration` как разделяемую переменную нехорошо было опрашивать без мьютекса, исправил.

Comment: В качестве рекламы вражеских языков, вот как той же функциональности достичь на C#: http://pastebin.com/pP81W34s